# Packet tracer help with routing between multiple company routers with vlans and wireless routers

Tags: vlan, ip, wireless, route

Im still quite a novice to packet tracer (so im sorry if this has been answered) and I'm trying to ping both vlans at company1 router to both Lans at company2 router but for some reason when the packet was sent out to the ISP router it went to company3 router instead of company1 router so I can't figure out why (ps. I've already trunked both vlans and set the ip route). Also, The wireless router at company4 is unable to ping outside the LAN, i thought that maybe it was because of the wireless router being one way so i tried replacing the wireless router with a regular router temporarily to see if that was the issue but no luck so now im stumped, any help will be appreciated.[image: Topology Picture]

edit: c1, c3, c4, s1, s2 runs below (updated).

C1

```
    Current configuration : 944 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname C1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524EGSM-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.21.0.1 255.255.248.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.21.200.1 255.255.248.0
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.21.200.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

C3

```
    Current configuration : 911 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname C3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524QS7D-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.21.4.2 255.255.248.0
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

C4

```
    Current configuration : 926 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname C4
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX15244A2X-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.21.240.1 255.255.248.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 10.21.210.1 255.255.248.0
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.21.210.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

S1

```
    Current configuration : 2496 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname company1_Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,200
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,200
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 no ip address
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

S2

```
    Current configuration : 2498 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname company1_switch_2
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,200
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,200
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan200
 no ip address
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Sounds like your routers' routing tables aren't correct. Please add the router configurations to your question (as text and using the `{}` editor function). We cannot simply guess what you did wrong.

Comment: A router bases its forwarding decision on its routing table - where are your routes coming from? There are neither static routes nor a routing protocol like OSPF or RIP.

Comment: updated show runs to include routes. (Im currently using only static and default routes for now)

Comment: Are those configs complete now? I don't see proper VLAN creation, VLAN trunking, and there are only default routes - does the ISP router have a proper routing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your routers only has a default route pointing to the ISP router in the middle. Unless that ISP router has got static routes to all the subnets behind each of the company routers, no packets will actually find their way.

Likewise, the subnet behind the wireless router isn't known to C4. Any packet destined (back) to that subnet can never find its way.